# How do I filter problems by multiple criteria? AND or OR

Tags: visual-studio-code, filter, vscode-problem-matcher

In the problems pane you can filter/exclude by text or file, but what if I want to filter by multiple criteria? Like filter messages for those that contain the text X OR Y (or X AND Y). I know you can filter for multiple types of files by using commas, is there a similar mechanism for text?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, this is still not possible to do generically as of Oct 2022. [This issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/62531) discusses the problem and links to more specific issues.

However, the `,` seems to be an `OR` operator. The filter below works for me for Python development. I want issues to be ignored for interactive (notebook) sessions as well as for a `scratch.py` file that I use to sketch out ideas before putting them in assets:

`!scratch.py,!Interactive*`

The `PROBLEMS` tab still shows the total count of "problems" (see 21 in the example below), but none of those problems are in files that I care about.[image]

Answer (score 1):

An extension I wrote, [Problems: Copy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.problems-copy) allows you to filter text using a regex.  So you could do something like this:

```
{
  "key": "alt+c",                      // whatever keybinding you want, no default
  "command": "problems-copy.copyAll",
  "args": {
    "errors": true,                   // will be included in the result
    "warnings": true,
    // "hints": true,          // any category not in the keybinding will NOT be in the result
    "informations": true,
    
    "messageFilter": "/const2|typeof/",   // wrapped in regex literals
  }
}
```

So that will copy problems with the word `const2` or `typeof`.  With the appropriate regex you should be able to construct the filter you want.

---

This extension cannot actually filter the problems that appear in the Problems Panel - that functionality is not available in the extension api.  With the extension you can copy/paste the filtered problems to another editor though (or spreadsheet, etc.).

Comment: Well it's a shame that it can't be done but thanks for the alternative